# Sybase SQL Anywhere - Unable to export data to file

Tags: export, sqlanywhere, isql

I am attempting to export a query in Sybase SQl Anywhere but am receiving an error when getting to the OUTPUT TO command. My query looks like this:

```
SELECT User_Name as 'Remote Database', nDaysBehind as 'Days Behind', Time_Received as 'Last Message Received'
FROM DailySynchRptView
WHERE Time_Received < today() -1 AND nDaysBehind > 0
ORDER BY Time_Received ASC 
OUTPUT TO c:\daysbehind.txt format ascii
```

The information that shows up in ISQL when I leave off the "OUTPUT TO" is the following:

```
Remote Database,Days Behind,Last Message Received
'Rem00027',23,'2011-02-23 16:10:14.000'
'Rem00085',7,'2011-03-11 04:47:02.000'
'Rem00040',5,'2011-03-13 15:22:15.000'
'Rem00074',4,'2011-03-14 16:01:25.000'
'Rem00087',3,'2011-03-15 06:04:16.000'
```

However, when the OUTPUT TO command is placed in the query, I receive the following error:

```
Could not execute statement.
Syntax error near 'OUTPUT' on line 5
SQLCODE=-131, ODBC 3 State="42000"
Line 1, column 1
```

I am open to any suggestions that might help me be able to export the data from the query. I have ran a similar query that returns a single line of information and it does export without errors.

Answer (score 3):

After a while looking at the code, I found that I was missing a semi-colon `;` to separate the two sets of commands. Once I added the semi-colon before the OUTPUT line, I was able to export the information.

Comment: FYI There is a SQL Anywhere-specific Q&A site at sqlanywhere-forum.sybase.com.